# Delphi Word automation: how to insert text after a table?

Tags: delphi

I have a Microsoft Word document with a table in it. My problem is that I need some text after the table but when I use `Selection.TypeText(Text)` after the table, the text is shown inside the table and not after/outside the table. 
How can I insert text after the table?

Code shown below:

```
Table := MSWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(MSWord.Selection.Range, 2, 1);
Table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text := 'GreenDay';
Table.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text := 'Kiss';
MSWord.Selection.TypeText('cdassda');
```

My second problem is that I am not able to append data to a new page:

```
MSWord.Selection.Goto(wdGoToPage, wdGoToLast);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Table.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text := 'GreenDay';
Table.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text := 'Kiss';
MSWord.Selection.EndKey( Unit:=wdStory);
MSWord.Selection.TypeParagraph;
MSWord.Selection.TypeText('cdassda');
```

Regarding your second point, this works for me:

```
//MSWord.Selection.Goto(wdGoToPage, wdGoToLast);

MSWord.Selection.EndKey( Unit:=wdStory );
MSWord.Selection.InsertBreak( Type:=wdPageBreak);

MSWord.Selection.TypeText('next page');
```