# delphi 10.2 add paragraph after table in word -

Tags: delphi, ms-word

1.I am creating word doccument from delphi Xe 10.2 . First I insert a table . After table the next paragraph coming inside the cell of the first table .How I exit out of the table and add a new line below the table

```
MSWord.Selection.Font.Size := 11;
MSWord.Selection.Font.name :='Bookman Old Style';
Table := MSWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add( Range:= MSWord.Selection.Range, 
NumRows:=1, NumColumns:= 3, DefaultTableBehavior:= wdWord9TableBehavior);
Cell := Table.Cell(1, 1);
Range := Cell.Range;
Range.Select;
MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment :=wdAlignParagraphCenter;
S :='A. No. VIII/48/94/2018- ';
MSWord.Selection.TypeText(Text := S);

Cell := Table.Cell(1, 3);
Range := Cell.Range;
Range.Select;
MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment :=wdAlignParagraphCenter;
S :='Dated:';
MSWord.Selection.TypeText(Text := S);

MSWord.Selection.TypeText('PART-A OF THE REPORT ');
Range:= MSWord.Selection.Range;
MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphCenter;}
```

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104173/delphi-word-automation-insert-text-after-the-tabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you did not read my comment to your query earlier on your other q, where I explained how to work this out for yourself)

Just add the following code immediately after yours:

```
  MSWord.Selection.EndKey( Unit:=wdStory );
  MSWord.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment := wdAlignParagraphJustify;
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('After table');
```

It is the `EndKey` which actually does the movement out of the table.

Comment: Thank you very much , I am a beginer in delphi -

Comment: when I insert second table after the paragraph , the colum width of the second  table changing

Comment: You can easily set the width of a table column, or even an individual cell, iirc.  Google for an example.